# How to Click on Print button on Print preview page using Python or Robot framework

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, robotframework

I have a website, were I need to verify the print functionality. I have clicked on print icon on a website and it opened me a new window with print preview page. In this page, I need to click on print icon.Below is code I was trying with robot framework + Python

Sampleprint.robot

```
*** Settings ***
Library    Selenium2Library
Library    printfunc.py

*** Test Case ***
Validate Downloads Page Title
    Open Browser    http://samplewebsite.com   chrome
    wait until page contains element  //*[@id="introduction-container"]  10s
    keypress
    sleep  4s
    ${output}=    Get Title Present Under Shadow Root Element
```

printfunc.py

```
from robot.libraries.BuiltIn import BuiltIn


def expand_shadow_element(driver, element):
    shadow_root = driver.execute_script('return arguments[0].shadowRoot', element)
    return shadow_root


def get_title_present_under_shadow_root_element():
    selenium2lib = BuiltIn().get_library_instance('Selenium2Library')
    # following line returns webdriver initiated in robot-framework
    driver = selenium2lib.driver

    # # shadow root locator - preceding tag of #shadow-root
    root1 = driver.find_element_by_tag_name('print-preview-app')
    shadow_root1 = expand_shadow_element(driver, root1)
    return shadow_root1
```

When execute this script, it always show me below error message

**NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"print-preview-app"}**

Can someone help me on this?

Comment: I am looking at your sample code but I am not seeing where you switch to new window. Selenium does not see when a new window opens, you must switch to it with a keyword.

Answer (score 1):

I can't judge exactly without seeing the html of the page, but it's most likely an iframe impact.

Check if there is an iframe on top of the element you are looking for, and if so see the section on switching iframes from the following sources

```
from robot.libraries.BuiltIn import BuiltIn

def expand_shadow_element(driver, element):
    shadow_root = driver.execute_script('return arguments[0].shadowRoot', element)
    return shadow_root

def get_title_present_under_shadow_root_element():
    selenium2lib = BuiltIn().get_library_instance('Selenium2Library')
    # following line returns webdriver initiated in robot-framework
    driver = selenium2lib.driver

    #add iframe
    driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_tag_name("iframe"))

    # # shadow root locator - preceding tag of #shadow-root
    root1 = driver.find_element_by_tag_name('print-preview-app')
    shadow_root1 = expand_shadow_element(driver, root1)
    return shadow_root1
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But there is no iframe in that html page.